# Backbone Coffeescript Super Render

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, coffeescript

How can I call the super's render function in backbone (coffeescript)?

If not in coffeescript, I've heard

```
MyModel.__super__.render.call(this);
```

will work, but MyModel in this case is exports.MyModel, how do I use this function if its an element of exports?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you calling render from inside the render function of the subclass?

Comment: yes, that is what I am going for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to call the super render method from inside the render method you could just something like this:

```
class TopLevelClass extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    @render()

  render: ->
    console.log 'Render TopLevelClass'
    @ # return this

class SecondaryLevelClass extends TopLevelClass
  initialize: ->
    @render()

  render: ->
    super()
    console.log 'Render SecondaryLevelClass'
    @ # return this

t = new TopLevelClass
  # el: $("#first_div")
s = new SecondaryLevelClass
  # el: $("#second_div")
```

Source:
http://coffeescript.org/#classes

edit:
@lublushokolad is correct. The [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render) recommends that `render` returns `this`

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, this does not work if you use the traditional backbone method of doing `SecondaryLevelClass = TopLevelClass.extend`, you actually do need to use this `extends` syntax provided by CoffeeScript

Answer (score 1):

There are some drawbacks to the coffeescript class approach in a Backbone environment:

1. Using the `class SecondaryLevelClass extends TopLevelClass` syntax changes the traditional Backbone extension model, which could be confusing.
2. It generates a lot of JS code, and you've already loaded Backbone/Underscore's extend code.

It may be worth using the regular Backbone extend syntax with the tradeoff of calling super in a more verbose way, like this:

```
TopLevelClass Backbone.View.extend
  initialize: -> @render()
  render: ->
    console.log 'Render TopLevelClass'
    @

SecondaryLevelClass = TopLevelClass.extend
  initialize: -> @render()
  render: ->
    SecondaryLevelClass.__super__.initialize.call(this)
    console.log 'Render SecondaryLevelClass'
    @

t = new TopLevelClass # el: $("#first_div")
s = new SecondaryLevelClass # el: $("#second_div")
```

Another option is a mixin like this: http://pivotallabs.com/a-convenient-super-method-for-backbone-js/